# insert bold tag in cursor position of div contenteditable

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have a content editable div and an event that fires everytime i enter "@" to mention a person when i chose the tagged person from a drop down i auto complete the fullname in the value of the div at the carret position, i wanted to add it inside a  tag but after i do  it sticks to writing in bold. how can i go back to writing normal after inserting the node

here is the function that inserts the tag :

```
 insertTagInDiv(val: string): void {
    const range = window.getSelection()?.getRangeAt(0);
    const newElement = document.createElement("b");
    newElement.innerHTML = val;
    range?.deleteContents();
    range?.insertNode(newElement);
  }
```

the template is pretty simple :

```
 <div class="chat-action-container">
    <div
      ref="roomTextarea"
      class="chat-text"
      contenteditable
      data-test="chat-text-area"
      @input="onInput"
    ></div>
    <OperationChatUserTagPanel
      ref="userTagList"
      :current-taggable-user="currentTaggableUser"
      :is-tagging="isTaggingUser"
      :last-at-coordinates="lastAtCoordinates"
      :message="message"
      :taggable-users="getTaggableUserList"
      @set-tag-user="setActive"
      @tag-user="tagUser"
    />
    <div class="chat-actions">
      <div
        class="chat-send-action"
        data-test="send-message-button"
        @click="sendMessage"
      >
        Envoyer
      </div>
    </div>
  </div
```

and the function that tags (which i want to insert the styled tag in the editable div is :

```
 tagUser(id: string): void {
    const user = this.chatMembers.find(
      (member) => member.id === id
    ) as TaggableUser;
    const remainingChunkAfterCurrentTag = this.message.slice(
      this.getCaretCharOffset(),
      this.message.length
    );

    this.message =
      this.message.substring(0, this.lastAtIndex) +
      `@${user.firstName} ${user.lastName} ${remainingChunkAfterCurrentTag} `;
    this.getTextareaRef.innerText = this.message;
    this.setCaretPosition();
    this.taggingUser = false;
  }
```

Comment: This is not a good use of Vue at all.  You should rarely need to ever manipulate the DOM manually.  Study the Vue documentation or watch some tutorials on how Vue works and rethink your entire approach here.  If you have some specific text that should be bold, you would normally just apply a class name to the element or component in your template and have that class tied to a style that applies bold font

Comment: rarely applies to this situation, i have done extensive research and everyone who does mention input with styling uses this but i can't seem to get the problem

Comment: Styling inputs or parts of inputs is very easily doable with Vue using classes, styles and/or bindings. Why use Vue if you're just going to manipulate the DOM yourself? You take all the power and efficiency away from Vue's handling of the DOM/virtual DOM when you most likely are simply unaware of how to solve your problem with Vue best practices.  What you describe should 100% be solvable without manually manipulating the DOM.  Post more code, the whole component if you can, or better would be repo or online sandbox reproducing your issue so I can take a closer look at your problem.

Comment: i just did, it would be amazing if you could help i've been trying for 2 weeks now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the key to understanding your issue is the fact that you're inserting text into a contenteditable div. They're honestly pretty tricky to work with and not what I expected when reading your original question.  This is the solution I came up with:
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-easley-ig0r32).

The codesandbox is a much simplified version of your code, just concentrating on inserting bold text into a contenteditable div with other text still using normal font styling.

The key was to isolate the inserted text from the rest of the div by putting it inside it's own div with `contenteditable=false`.  I also had to make sure it stayed inline with the rest of the text using `display: inline-block`.  This solution may need more work in order to match 100% of your specific application's requirements but should hopefully help you get close to your desired functionality.

Comment: you're a life saver, i'm gonna try to make it match my requirement! thanks a lot